# How to apply the not_analyzed to a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add  **not_analyzed** to a url field. I tried to with the field type string  its gave me **Failed to parse mapping [doc]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [url]** and I replaced the type with text and i got **Failed to parse mapping [doc]: Could not convert [url.index] to boolean** exception. How can I make the filed url not_analyzed

```
 PUT /some_index
    {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": 5,
                "number_of_replicas": 1,
                "refresh_interval": "60s",
                "analysis" : {
                  "analyzer" : {
                    "my_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_snow","asciifolding","english_stop"]
                    }
                  },
                  "filter" : {
                    "my_snow" : {
                        "type" : "snowball",
                        "language" : "Lovins"
                    },
                    "english_stop": {
              "type":        "stop",
              "stopwords":"_english_"
            }
                }
            }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "_source": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "true",
                        "store": true,
                               "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
                                "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "index": "true",
                        "store": true

                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "true",
                        "store": true,
                                "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
                                "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"

                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                         "store": true,
                        "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try: remove index: not_analyzed and change the field type to keyword instead of text

Comment: If i change this field type to keyword,In Kibana url field doesn't show in the filter list.

Comment: Did you refresh your field list? Kibana -> Management -> Index Patterns (under kibana tab) -> on the right the little reload icon

Comment: Yes I refreshed the field its working thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elasticsearch 5.0 removed the `not_analyzed` setting. In its place, the `string` type was broken into two: `text` which is analyzed, and `keyword` which is not. Read more on this blog post: [Strings are dead, long live strings!](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Assuming you're running 5.0+, your mapping has an illegal value. Also, it's conflicting: you say you don't want the `url` to be analyzed, but you specified an analyzer: `"search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"`

If you don't want the field analyzed, you should set your url field up the same as you did the host:

```
"url": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

Otherwise, make the type `text`:

```
"url": {
    "type": "text",
    "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```